# Multiple Spectrum Color Palette

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to figure out why I cant get multiple color selectors to open on my spectrum color palette. A jsfiddle is at the end.

HTML

```
<label>
<input name="cand_no" type="text" />
</label>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="initial_oneColor">
<table id="initialTable1" width="630" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Colors</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id="showPaletteOnly" class="test" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="template" style="display: none">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id="showPaletteOnly" class="test" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('[name="cand_no"]').on('change', function () {
    // Not checking for Invalid input
    if (this.value != '') {
        var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);

        for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
            // Clone the Template
            var $cloned = $('.template tbody').clone();
            // For each Candidate append the template row
            $('#initialTable1 tbody').append($cloned.html());
        }
    }
});

$(".test").spectrum({
    color: "white",
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    change: function (color) {
        printColor(color);
    },
    palette: [
    //White, blank, red, green, blue
    ["rgb(255, 255, 255)", "rgb(0, 0, 0)", "rgb(237, 10, 21)",
        "rgb(6, 247, 108)", "rgb(6, 137, 255)"],

    //sky blue, light blue, silver, mint, off white
    ["rgb(0, 194, 252)", "rgb(8, 240, 252)", "rgb(192, 191, 197)",
        "rgb(171, 211, 202)", "rgb(255, 239, 240)"],

    //purple, lavendar, hotpink, pink, light pink
    ["rgb(115, 111, 250)", "rgb(222, 190, 239)", "rgb(245, 21, 154)",
        "rgb(219, 57, 204)", "rgb(245, 194, 227)"],

    //blush, orange, yellow, warm white, turqoise
    ["rgb(201, 95, 167)", "rgb(212, 54, 27)", "rgb(222, 242, 49)",
        "rgb(243, 228, 195)", "rgb(1, 220, 164)"], ]
});
```

I basically want to allow the user to type in a number into text box, is generates that many color selection boxes, and then the user can select a color for each box. I cant figure out why only the first box opens the color selection.

Also if anyone has any idea how I could have a randomize with this as well to randomly generate the colors instead of hand selecting.

http://jsfiddle.net/zredmonkeyz/nrsb9oqh/

I am trying to create something similar to this site: http://swatchspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this code below, what it does is only markup `new` spectrums and then intialises these after each `change` event as well as on first load of the page to make sure the first one is initialised.  As for random color you can have a look at a method to do that below too

```
$('[name="cand_no"]').on('change', function () {
    // Not checking for Invalid input
    if (this.value != '') {
        var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);

        for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
            // Clone the Template
            var $cloned = $('.template tbody').clone();
            // For each Candidate append the template row
            $('#initialTable1 tbody').append($cloned.html());
        }
        makeSpectrums();
    }
});

function myRandomColor() {
    var color = 'rgb(';
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        color += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ', ';
    }
    color += ')';
    console.log(color);
    return color;
}

function makeSpectrums() {
    $(".newSpectrum").not('.template .newSpectrum').spectrum({
        color: myRandomColor(),
        showPaletteOnly: true,
        change: function (color) {
            printColor(color);
        },
        palette: [
        //White, blank, red, green, blue
        ["rgb(255, 255, 255)", "rgb(0, 0, 0)", "rgb(237, 10, 21)",
            "rgb(6, 247, 108)", "rgb(6, 137, 255)"],

        //sky blue, light blue, silver, mint, off white
        ["rgb(0, 194, 252)", "rgb(8, 240, 252)", "rgb(192, 191, 197)",
            "rgb(171, 211, 202)", "rgb(255, 239, 240)"],

        //purple, lavendar, hotpink, pink, light pink
        ["rgb(115, 111, 250)", "rgb(222, 190, 239)", "rgb(245, 21, 154)",
            "rgb(219, 57, 204)", "rgb(245, 194, 227)"],

        //blush, orange, yellow, warm white, turqoise
        ["rgb(201, 95, 167)", "rgb(212, 54, 27)", "rgb(222, 242, 49)",
            "rgb(243, 228, 195)", "rgb(1, 220, 164)"]]
    }).removeClass('newSpectrum');
}
makeSpectrums();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/nrsb9oqh/7/

Comment: Rob thanks so much, I didn't even think about making it its own function and referencing the class inside it.

Also as far as the random thing, I did manage to have that code before, however I wasnt completely clear with what I meant by random. I meant randomly select from the palette I defined, not a random RGB value.

Comment: @user3130128 To make them all start with a random color http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/t06htfbd/